# column data type (int to bigint) change impact on tableau reports

Tags: mysql, tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

We were using tableau as BI tool and in one of the reporting database (mysql) all the ID integer fields data type getting changed from int to bigint.
We anticipate no impact on tableau reports and to be on safer side, planning to test few existing reports after the data type change as well.
To be on a safer side, wanted to check, whether this will have any direct or indirect impact on any of the tableau reports in some form and any other additional checks or testing need to be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We arn't in a position to make a judgement call on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau understands two data types Integer and Float. If you use BIGINT, it will have no visible impact.